# SQL How to update data if the value given is not null/empty

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update, isnull

I have a table of users
and I want users to update some of their details (data), but if a user decided not insert a value and send it empty, I want the data   to remain with same value.

This doesn't work for me at all if I insert -

```
exec UpdateAboutMe '','','',21  To this proc:
```

[image: this is the proc]

I can't copy the code to here: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" I tried for a half an hour to change it and the same message comes on and on - I uploaded a screenshot

It erased the user data and its empty.

[image: row affected]

I tried so many ways, not to say million in one day/night
and didn't succeed.

what is the right way ?
To make it clear this is the opposite of what I want  -

```
    SET @AboutMe= IsNull(@AboutMe, [About_me])
```

So if @AboutMe sent empty, [About_me] will not cleared/erased.
Thanks.

Comment: Never store the age in a table, this will not update automatically every year.

Comment: Don't Store Passwords and Do Not Write Your Own Security.  Do not store symmetric passwords.  Do not store passwords in clear text.  FYI - The pattern Gordon Linoff suggests below is the answer to your question - specifically the second part of his answer.

Comment: @SqlSurfer Why do not store passwords?  this is not real man, just sql. nothing secret friend.

Comment: @WolfgangK Hi, how can I "ask" user to insert his birth date at certain patern as for example - 20/5/1992 (and not for example 05.20.1992) in c# Webservice with [WebMethod] ? or I'm mistaken and it's not important because at the Javascript or react it will show the right pattren to insert.(I'm a beginner)

Comment: @Doywaser how did you "ask" the user to enter her age and make sure it's not "abc"? If you want an answer about c# or JavaScript, tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are being passed in as `NULL`, then you can simply do:

```
SET AboutMe = COALESCE(@AboutMe, About_me)
```

If they can be `NULL` or blank, then you can use an explicit `CASE`:

```
SET AboutMe = (CASE WHEN @AboutMe IS NULL OR LTRIM(@AboutMe) = '' THEN Aboutme ELSE @AboutMe END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` to replace a value with itself if a variable `IS NULL` or an empty string or just white spaces. Otherwise use the value of the variable. This is possible e.g. by using a combination of `ltrim()`, `isnull()` and a comparison to the empty string.

```
UPDATE [Users_Table]
       SET [User_name] = CASE
                           WHEN ltrim(isnull(@User_name, '')) = '' THEN
                             [User_name]
                           ELSE
                             @User_name
                         END,
           [About_me] = CASE
                          WHEN ltrim(isnull(@AboutMe, '')) = '' THEN
                            [About_me]
                          ELSE
                            @AboutMe
                        END,
           [City] = CASE
                      WHEN ltrim(isnull(@City, '')) = '' THEN
                        [City]
                      ELSE
                        @City
                    END
       WHERE [UserID] = @ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you also want to "ignore" `''` but the problem is this isn't `NULL`.

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC UpdateMy
  @User_name nvarchar(15),
  @AboutMe nvarchar(150),
  @City nvarchar(21),
  @ID int
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Users_Table
  SET
    [User_name] = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@User_name, N'') = N'' THEN [User_name] ELSE @User_name END,
    [About_me] = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@AboutMe, N'') = N'' THEN [About_me] ELSE @AboutMe END,
    [City] = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@City, N'') = N'' THEN [City] ELSE @City END
  WHERE [UserID] = @ID;

  SELECT * FROM Users_Table WHERE [UserID] = @ID;
END
GO
```